# How to configure Apache CXF to use a single JAXBContext through a Non-Spring configuration file?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I have read that sharing a single JAXBContext object across multiple threads can greatly reduce the CPU usage of an application that uses JAXB. A proof of this is [here](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2011/09/jaxbcontext-performance-problem-case.html). We are currently using Apache CXF for developing web services. Apache CXF is bound to use JAXB by default.

- According to [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-SingleJAXBContextandextrauserclasses), Apache CXF can be configured to use a single instance of JAXBContext through a configuration file.
- According to [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html), we can supply a configuration file to CXF. This configuration file is a Spring configuration file.
- According to [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html#ServletTransport-UsingtheservlettransportwithoutSpring), Apache CXF can be used without Spring.

Given the above information, how do I configure Apache CXF to use a single JAXBContext without using a Spring based configuration file since I am looking at a code base that uses the servlet transport without Spring? Are there any other configuration parameters that can be added for the JAXBContext that will further improve the performance?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solution proposed [here](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Use-single-JAXBContext-for-multiple-web-services-td4670019.html), based on the definition of a Global JAXBContext, but I'm not sure it will play well with jax-rs.

A simpler solution without spring would be to define your own `@Provider`, extending `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider`, and register it in cxf, using the `openejb-jar.xml` file for instance, if you are working with [tomee](https://openejb.apache.org/developer/configuration/cxf.html).

Your provider would look like:

```
@Provider
public class MyJAXBElementProvider<T> extends JAXBElementProvider<T> {
  public MyJAXBElementProvider() {
    super();
    setSingleJaxbContext(true);
    setExtraClass(...);
  }
}
```

and it would need to be registered in the `WEB-INF/openejb-jar.xml` file in your webapp like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openejb-jar>
  <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
    <properties>
    cxf.jaxrs.providers = mypackage.MyJAXBElementProvider
    </properties>
  </pojo-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```